# Drupal site profiling

Tags: drupal, optimization, profiling

Trying to locate the bottleneck in our drupal site. I've installed xhprof to profile but honestly I have no idea what "normal" numbers would be on Drupal. I was hoping I could get some pointers or if anyone knows of a tutorial that goes over this specifically for Drupal...?

Here are the top items when I sort by Exclu. CPU. Again I'm not sure what columns are most important to look at and what is "normal". I'll gladly add more info if needed.

[image]

Comment: Install the devel module and take a look at your database queries. See if you're doing a lot of them or if any are going really slow.

Comment: I have devel installed and can see the db queries that are run. What is "a lot" and "slow"?...My home page shows close to 400 queries. There are a couple that show up in red (just over 5 milliseconds). If this is a lot of queries, how do I trim it down if that is what the business requires of the site?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what modules you have, and what the queries are doing. 400 is definitely excessive in most cases, and it's probably the main reason things are slow.

Answer (score 0):

What database engine are you using? _db_query functions shouldn't take up that much of the load time. Make sure you have a clean connection to the database server, and that its set up properly.

Comment: I set up the connection in settings.php according to the installation documents for drupal. Not sure what else needs to be done so that it is clean and set up properly. How do I tell if it's not?